# FileNotFoundError when using shutil.copy()

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I want to copy the source file to the destination folder.
In the destination folder, I am creating n number of folders (That may be nested of any depth) and I want to paste file1.pdf in any random folders inside the destination folder.

I have done the following code

```
import shutil
destination_folder = "path_to_the_destination_folder"
source_file = "path_to_source_file\file1.pdf"
destination_file = "f{destination_folder}\any_random_folder_from_n_nested_folders\file1.pdf"
new_file= shutil.copy(source_file, destination_file )
print(new_file)
```

FYI: `"destination_folder\any_random_folders_from_n_nested_folders"` This path is present, means it is getting created successfully , checked using os.path.isdir()
And **facing this issue for some files**, not for all files..

But it is giving me an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 420, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 265, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `print(source_file, destination_file)`? Have you escaped the backslashes in your file path?

Comment: I can see source and destination file like this respectively :   

D:\source_folder\file1.pdf 

`D:\destination_folder\fld162195222873318\fld1621952229676592\fld1621952229678546\fld1621952229996922\fld1621952229999853\fld1621952230142439\fld162195223029577\fld1621952230315301\fld1621952230327996\fld1621952230337761\file1.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you have incorrectly specified destination folder, try this:

```
import shutil
destination_folder = "path_to_the_destination_folder"
source_file = "path_to_source_file\file1.pdf"
destination = f"{destination_folder}\any_random_folders_from_n_nested_folders\file1.pdf"
dest = shutil.copy(source_file, destination)
print(dest)
```

If this doesn't work, then check if all the directories exist and also check the permissions.

Comment: No actually, the destination path is correct.
I should edit my code from question as you mentioned.

Comment: what you edited is incorrect, check the representation correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is resolved..
I just changed folder names which I was creating according to user input.

- Previous folder names: `f"Fld+{datetimestamp}"`
- Current folder names: `f"Fld+{folder_counter}"`